# What do I need to do to have the new version of Animate run Actionscript 2.0?

Tags: flash, actionscript, actionscript-2, adobe-animate

I am currently trying to work on a old flash file that was written with Actionscript 2.0. How can I debug this file. I am trying to open it in animate but cannot figure out how to change the ActionScript to 2.0 from 3.0 (Publish settings only has the option for 3.0). Is there something else I need to install to use Actionscript 2.0? Should I use another program to debug? I am trying to make some changes to the logic of the flash app before converting it to HTML5 later this year.

Comment: Animate doesn't support AS2. You need to go back to at least CS6: https://community.adobe.com/t5/animate/ability-to-add-actionscript-2-0-support-in-flash-cc/td-p/5193356?page=1

Comment: I can't seem to find a way to get CS6 through CC anymore, is this right?